# How can I find the volume enclosed by the following graphs?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, volume

How do I find the volume bound by planes $x=0$, $y=0$, and the surfaces $x=-4y^2+3$, $z=x^3y$?

I think that I probably need to do:

$$\iint_D (x^3y) \, dx\,dy $$

But I'm not sure what to do for the limits. I think that for the $x$ I should use $0$ and $-4y^2+3$, but I don't know what to do about the $y$.

EDIT: I tried using 0 and 3 for the limits for $x$, and $0$ and $\frac{\sqrt{3-x}}{2}$ as limits for the $y$, but I got half of the answer that I was supposed to get ($\frac{243}{80}$).

Comment: Have you drawn the solid described by those surfaces?  That's usually the first step in determining the limits of integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note $y^2=-\frac 14(x-3)$ (See [it](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%204y%5E2%2Bx%3D3)) thus
$$I=2\int_{0}^{3}\int_{0}^{\frac{\sqrt{3-x}}{2}}x^3\,y\,dydx=\frac 14\int_{0}^{3}(3x^3-x^4)dx$$

Comment: How do you get from $y^2 = -\frac{1}{4}(x - 3)$ to the limits being $\sqrt{3-x}$ and 0? Shouldn't you get $y = \frac{\sqrt{3-x}}{2}$? Additionally, when I evaluate your solution, I get $\frac{243}{40}$, exactly double the answer the book says I should get. However, if I do use $\frac{\sqrt{3-x}}{2}$ as one of the limits, I get half of the answer the book lists.

Comment: Yes it was typo

Comment: Okay, my only other question is why is it $2 \int_0^{\frac{\sqrt{3-x}}{2}} x^3 y  \, dy$ rather than $\int_0^{\frac{\sqrt{3-x}}{2}} x^3 y \, dy$ or  $\int_{-{\frac{\sqrt{3-x}}{2}}}^{\frac{\sqrt{3-x}}{2}} x^3 y \, dy$? Is it because it is a volume, and therefore shouldn't be negative, so you just multiply the positive part by two to account for the negative bit?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to Behrouz's answer, the solid lies over the plane region
$$
    D = \left\{(x,y)\mid - \sqrt{3}/2 \leq y \leq \sqrt{3}/2,\ 0 \leq x \leq -4y^2+3\right\}
$$
[It looks like this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?t=crmtb01&f=ob&i=x%20%E2%89%A50%20and%20x%20%E2%89%A4-4y%5E2%20%2B%203):

[image: set]

So the volume is
$$
    \int_{-\sqrt{3}/2}^{\sqrt{3}/2} \int_0^{3-4y^2} x^3y\,dx\,dy
$$

Comment: I tried that, but you get 0: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+(int+x%5E3*y+dx+from+0+to+3-4y%5E2)+dy+from+-sqrt(3)%2F2+to+sqrt(3)%2F2